NavigationManager.NavigateTo ignores base URI
I have an website developed in .net 8.0 blazor server side model.
In my app i have specified base href in app.razor file
<base href="/myapp/" />

it does append the myapp in images and css files but when it comes to c# ,
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("SomeRoute")

, it completely ignore base href value
for example
www.xyz.com/myapp is my website
Than NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Home") should result in

www.xyz.com/myapp/Home

Instead it results in

www.xyz.com/Home

Any clue why this is happening ?

This seems the similar question of this ASP.NET Core Navigation Manager not using `base href` value but with no answer.
After checking the source code of NavigationMager we can find an Initialize(baseUri,uri) method.
So a workaround is that you could try use a custom NavigationManager to initilize the BaseUri:
    public class MyNaviManager : NavigationManager
    {
        public MyNaviManager(NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
//inject navigationManger to get the current page URL
            Initialize("https://localhost/app/", navigationManager.Uri);
        }
    }

Then in program.cs
//because NavigationManger is scoped 
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyNaviManager>();

Test to modify Counter.razor
@page "/app/counter"
@inject MyNaviManager _myNaviManager
<button @onclick="test">test</button>
@code {
    private void test()
    {
        var baseUri = _myNaviManager.BaseUri;
        var uri = _myNaviManager.Uri;
    }
}

Result

Just note that the "Uri" represents the current page URL. It must contains the "baseURI". But if you don't care about what "uri" is, you could simply initilize like following
Initialize("https://localhost:7251/app/","https://localhost:7251/app/");

